# How to import custom options with price is 0 in magento 2

Tags: custom-options, magento2.3

I am trying to import the custom options with price 0 via backend. But it failed to save the price value with 0 and it throws an error like below.

> Notice: Undefined offset: 6336 in /var/www/html/xx/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product/Option.php on line 1474

By referring this link https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/4c76f9a441a564ade8e904cd99eed0827162ff9c

I have replaced the code as shown in the below image.

[image]

Then the option is imported correctly.

Can you tell me is this the right way to edit the core file?

By doing this, will it cause any issue in custom options?

Please guide me in the right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: id recommend u take a look to line 6335 and 6336 as that is were the issue lies

Answer (score 0):

**Some Code:**

> \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterfaceFactory
>   $customOptionFactory
>
> $options[$count] = [
>                       'title' => $singleTypeOption['option']['title'],
>                       'type' => $singleTypeOption['option']['type'],
>                       'is_require' => (int)$singleTypeOption['option']['is_require'],
>                       'price' => 0,
>                       'price_type' => 'fixed',
>                       'sku' => '',
>                       'max_characters' => 255,
>                       'values' => array()
>                   ];
>
> if(count($options)){
>               $customOptions = [];
>               foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
>                   $customOption = $this->customOptionFactory->create();
>                   $customOption->setData($arrayOption);
>                   $customOption->setProductSku($product->getSku());
>                   $customOptions[] = $customOption;
>               }
>               $product->setOptions($customOptions)->save();
>           }